# matchbox-keyboard - virtual keyboard loses focus in a web browser "password" field

Tags: linux, keyboard, yocto

I built a Linux distro using Yocto, for an ARM-based web-kiosk application.

The system works without any mouse or physical keyboard, but using only the touchscreen and a virtual keyboard, in particular the "matchbox-keyboard". The matchbox-keyboard runs as a daemons, as usually in these kind of application and appears automatically when the focus is on some text field.

Now, with a web browser (both Chromium and Firefox), entering in a typical "login" web page, all works good for the "username" field (the keyboard focus is correct and the matchbox-keyboard pops up automatically), but, after pressing TAB to fill the "password" field, the matchbox-keyboard disappears. And the keyboard doesn't appears even if you try to enter in the "password" text field directly, using the touchscreen.

Did anybody find a solution to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Flavio